# CSS Negative top margin not working with floats above

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to reduce the space between the text, 'What time is it?' and 'John Appleseed' a little using a negative margin. Between the class `chat-sample` and the elements above it. I used a negative margin but it has no effect.

```css
.panel-heading h1 {
 padding-bottom: 0.65em;
 color: #3399ff;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.col-xs-12 {
 padding-left: 0;
 padding-right: 0;
}

.chats {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.chats a {
 display: block;
 color: #000;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.chats .sender.left {
 margin-left: 10px;
}

.chats .chat-sample {
 clear: both;
 margin-left: 35px;
 margin-top: -15px;
}

.glyphicon-user {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #3399ff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='panel panel-default'>
     <div class='panel-heading'>
      <div class='btn-group pull-left'>
       <div class='dropdown'>
        <button class='btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' type='button'>
         <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog'</span>
        </button>
        <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
         <li><a href='#'>Delete All Chats</a></li>
         <li><a href='#'>Log Out</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class='btn-group pull-right'>
       <div class='dropdown'>
        <button class='btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' type='button'>
         <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'</span>
        </button>
        <ul class='dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right'>
         <li><a href='#'>New Chat</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
      <h1 class='panel-title text-center'>FunChat</h1>
     </div>
     <div class='panel-body'>
      <ul class='chats'>
       <li>
        <a href=''>
         <div class='chat-img pull-left'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'</span></div>
         <div class='sender left pull-left'><strong>John Appleseed</strong></div>
         <div class='timestamp text-muted pull-right'><small><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Thursday</small></div>
         <p class='chat-sample text-muted'>What time is it?</p>
        </a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Typo in `<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'</span>`

Comment: @j08691thanks. Still same result

Comment: Oh I was just noting it, not suggesting it as a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `clear: both` you should just `clear: right` and then you can use the relevant padding-top:

```css
.panel-heading h1 {
 padding-bottom: 0.65em;
 color: #3399ff;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.col-xs-12 {
 padding-left: 0;
 padding-right: 0;
}

.chats {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.chats a {
 display: block;
 color: #000;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.chats .sender.left {
 margin-left: 10px;
}

.chats .chat-sample {
 clear: right;
 margin-left: 35px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.glyphicon-user {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #3399ff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='panel panel-default'>
     <div class='panel-heading'>
      <div class='btn-group pull-left'>
       <div class='dropdown'>
        <button class='btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' type='button'>
         <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog'</span>
        </button>
        <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
         <li><a href='#'>Delete All Chats</a></li>
         <li><a href='#'>Log Out</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class='btn-group pull-right'>
       <div class='dropdown'>
        <button class='btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' type='button'>
         <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'</span>
        </button>
        <ul class='dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right'>
         <li><a href='#'>New Chat</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
      <h1 class='panel-title text-center'>FunChat</h1>
     </div>
     <div class='panel-body'>
      <ul class='chats'>
       <li>
        <a href=''>
         <div class='chat-img pull-left'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'</span></div>
         <div class='sender left pull-left'><strong>John Appleseed</strong></div>
         <div class='timestamp text-muted pull-right'><small><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Thursday</small></div>
         <p class='chat-sample text-muted'>What time is it?</p>
        </a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I like this answer, thanks! Any idea why the negative margin didn't work?

Comment: Because you used the clear :) this is what it supposed to do... clear the elements.

Comment: This is much better than my (deleted) solution!

Comment: Your solution works no matter the height of the icon on the left, definitely better.  Gave you a +1.

Comment: OK... so let me get this straight. With `clear: both` the glyphicon (being bigger) on the left moved the paragraph tag lower?

Comment: when you use `clear: both` you tell the element that it should "got down" (to the next line) based on both left-floating elements and right-floating elements. Since you have both elements there - that element moved to the next line, you you can't "pull" it up.

Comment: @RobertRocha That's exactly right, and also why Dekel's answer was better than mine.

Comment: Ahh ok makes sense. I was being contradictory with `clear: both` and negative margins. Now I see why Jonathan recommended the `position` solutions.